# How to snap my custom graphview thick lines to nearest multiple of 5?

Tags: android, graph, android-jetpack-compose, precision

I am creating a graphView like desmos in jetpack compose. Everything works fine. But In my code, when I am zooming in or zooming out, the thick lines should be at x(or y)=0,5,10,20 etc. Initially those lines are at the exact point. But after zooming in or out it becomes like 5.012, 10.006. Here is the code

```
import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTransformGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clipToBounds
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Size
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Paint
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.Stroke
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.drawIntoCanvas
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.nativeCanvas
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import kotlin.math.round

val gu= GraphViewUtils()
class GraphViewObj{
    var xBounds= arrayOf(0.0,0.0)
    var yBounds= arrayOf(0.0,0.0)
    var scaleX=1.0
    var scaleY=1.0
}

@Composable
fun GraphView(modifier: Modifier,graphViewObj:GraphViewObj, draw:DrawScope.()->Unit) {
    var xBounds by remember{ mutableStateOf(arrayOf(-10.0,10.0))}
    var yBounds by remember{ mutableStateOf(arrayOf(0.0,0.0))}
    var zum by remember {mutableStateOf(1.0) }
    
    val gridColor= Color.Gray
    val axesColor= Color.DarkGray

    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.clipToBounds().then(modifier)
        .pointerInput(Unit){
        detectTransformGestures { _, pan, zoom, _ ->
            val scaleX= (xBounds[1]-xBounds[0])/size.width
            val scaleY=(yBounds[1]-yBounds[0])/size.height
            if(scaleY!=0.0){
                xBounds= arrayOf((xBounds[0]-pan.x*scaleX)/zoom, (xBounds[1]-pan.x*scaleX)/zoom)
                yBounds= arrayOf((yBounds[0]-pan.y*scaleY)/zoom, (yBounds[1]-pan.y*scaleY)/zoom)
                graphViewObj.scaleX=scaleX
                graphViewObj.scaleY=scaleY
            }
            zum=zoom.toDouble()
        }
    },
        onDraw =
    {
        val heightToWidthRatio= size.height/size.width
        //Initializing ys
        if (yBounds[0]==0.0 && yBounds[1]==0.0){yBounds= arrayOf(xBounds[0]*heightToWidthRatio, xBounds[1]*heightToWidthRatio)}
        else{
            graphViewObj.xBounds=xBounds
            graphViewObj.yBounds=yBounds

            makeGrids(xBounds, yBounds,size,zum,gridColor,axesColor )
            draw()
        }
    })
    }
var step=0.0
fun DrawScope.makeGrids(
    xBounds: Array<Double>,
    yBounds: Array<Double>,
    size: Size,
    zoom:Double,
    gridColor: Color,
    axesColor: Color
) {
    val minX= xBounds[0]
    val maxX= xBounds[1]
    val minY=yBounds[0]
    val maxY=yBounds[1]
    val actualMaxX= size.width
    val actualMaxY=size.height
    val scaleX= (maxX-minX)/actualMaxX
    val scaleY= (maxY-minY)/actualMaxY
    val minStep=size.width/20.0
    val maxStep=minStep*2.0

    if (step>maxStep){step=minStep}
    else if(step<minStep){step=maxStep}
    step*=zoom

    Log.d("st",step.toString())
    val tempPoints=ArrayList<Double>()
    for (i in 0..40){
        tempPoints.add(i*step)
    }
    val verticalLines= ArrayList<Line>()
    val horizontalLines= ArrayList<Line>()
    tempPoints.forEachIndexed {index, it->
        //for translation of grid
        var x=it-minX/scaleX
        var y=it-minY/scaleY

        //correct if lines are out of bounds
        if (x>tempPoints.last()){ x= gu.correctX(x,tempPoints.last(),tempPoints.last()) }
        else if (x<0f){x= gu.correctX(x,0.0,tempPoints.last()) }

        if(y>tempPoints.last()){y=gu.correctX(y,tempPoints.last(),tempPoints.last())}
        else if(y<0f){y=gu.correctX(y,0.0,tempPoints.last())}

        val lineWidth=if (index%5==0){2.5f
        }else{ Stroke.HairlineWidth}
        if (y>=0.0 && y<actualMaxY){
            val hline=Line(arrayOf(Offset(0f,y.toFloat()),Offset(size.width,y.toFloat())), lineWidth,gridColor)
            horizontalLines.add(hline)
        }

        if (x>=0f && x<actualMaxX){
            val vline=Line(arrayOf(Offset(x.toFloat(),0f), Offset(x.toFloat(),size.height)), lineWidth, gridColor)
            verticalLines.add(vline)
        }
    verticalLines.forEach { drawLine(it.color,it.Offsets[0], it.Offsets[1],it.width) }
    horizontalLines.forEach { drawLine(it.color,it.Offsets[0],it.Offsets[1],it.width) }

        val xAxesY=-minY/scaleY
        val yAxesX= -minX/scaleX

        //draw axes
        drawLine(axesColor, Offset(0f,xAxesY.toFloat()), Offset(actualMaxX,xAxesY.toFloat()),5f)
        drawLine(axesColor, Offset(yAxesX.toFloat(),0f), Offset(yAxesX.toFloat(), actualMaxY), 5f)
        
//set labels
        if (index%5==0){
            val c=gu.getVirtulOffset(Offset(x.toFloat(),y.toFloat()),xBounds,yBounds,size)
            val xCoord= c.x.toDouble().toScientific()
            val yCoord=c.y.toDouble().toScientific()
            if(round( c.x*1000/xBounds[1])/1000.0!=0.0){setLabels(Offset(yAxesX.toFloat().coerceIn(10f,size.width-100f),y.toFloat()),yCoord)
                setLabels(Offset(x.toFloat(),xAxesY.toFloat().coerceIn(40f,size.height-40f)),xCoord)}else{setLabels(Offset(x.toFloat(),xAxesY.toFloat()),"0")}
            //set labels

        }

    }

}
```

the graphViewObj class is for user purposes, and the GraphViewUtils class is given below,

```
class GraphViewUtils {

    fun getActualOffset(offset: Offset, virtualXBounds:Array<Double>, virtualYBounds: Array<Double>, actualDim: Size):Offset{
        val xMin=virtualXBounds[0]
        val xMax= virtualXBounds[1]
        val yMin=virtualYBounds[0]
        val yMax=virtualYBounds[1]
        val scaleX= (xMax-xMin)/actualDim.width
        val scaleY= (yMax-yMin)/actualDim.height

        return Offset(((offset.x-xMin)/scaleX).toFloat(),((-offset.y-yMin)/scaleY).toFloat())
    }
    fun getVirtulOffset(offset: Offset, virtualXBounds: Array<Double>, virtualYBounds: Array<Double>,actualDim: Size):Offset{
        val xMin=virtualXBounds[0]
        val xMax= virtualXBounds[1]
        val yMin=virtualYBounds[0]
        val yMax=virtualYBounds[1]
        val scaleX= (xMax-xMin)/actualDim.width
        val scaleY= (yMax-yMin)/actualDim.height

        return Offset((offset.x*scaleX +xMin).toFloat(), -(offset.y*scaleY+yMin).toFloat())
    }

     fun correctX(x:Double,boundary:Double=0.0, correctFactor:Double):Double{
        var correctedX=x
        if (correctedX<=boundary){
            while (correctedX<boundary){
                correctedX+=correctFactor
            }
        }
        else{
           while (correctedX>boundary){
               correctedX-=correctFactor
           }
        }
        return correctedX
    }

}
```

I suspected that while zooming and setting step value to minStep or maxStep ,the value of xbounds (boundary) are not perfectly 5 or 10 etc. But I don't know how to fix it. Help me. Thanks in advance.